# Convert Nested List of Integers to a two dimensional array using Streams ( List<List<Integer>> -> int[][] )

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I searched for similar questions but I found only for the object String which dont apply to this case:

Want to convert `List<List<Integer>> list` to `int[][] array` using streams

So far I got this:

```
int[][] array= list.stream().map(List::toArray)...
```

I used as a base other similar questions I found. But these use String and can't make it work for Integers->int:

```
// Example with String 1:    
String[][] array = list.stream()
        .map(l -> l.stream().toArray(String[]::new))
        .toArray(String[][]::new);

// Example with String 2:    
    final List<List<String>> list = ...;
    final String[][] array = list.stream().map(List::toArray).toArray(String[][]::new);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You only need to make a few modifications to the `String[][]` solution:

```
List<List<Integer>> lists = ...;
int[][] arrays = lists.stream()                                // Stream<List<Integer>>
        .map(list -> list.stream().mapToInt(i -> i).toArray()) // Stream<int[]>
        .toArray(int[][]::new);
```

The `mapToInt(i -> i)` is unboxing each `Integer` (i.e. `Integer` → `int`).

See:

- [`Stream#mapToInt(ToIntFunction)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#mapToInt(java.util.function.ToIntFunction))
- [`IntStream#toArray()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#toArray())